# Pandas and tab delimited files with a doublequote inside a field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have data exported from a program in tab-delimited format "test.exp":

```
"HEADER"    "ID"    "Part Reference"    "Value" "Part_Description"
"PARTOCC:17306" "17306" "M1"    "48SL-5S-50-C-LF"   "Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat"
"PARTOCC:17310" "17310" "M2"    "48SL-5S-50-C-LF"   "Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat"
"PARTOCC:65494" "65494" "J4E"   "311P822-MC-095-BS-D"   "GSFC CPCI J3 RA MALE 95 Position 0.123" tails"
```

Note there are no options in the output formatting of this program and we have lots of these files to ingest into a parts database.
Note the 5.00" embedded in the tab-delimited file.

Put this file in a dataframe and write it back out:

```
import pandas as pd

exp_fn = r"test.exp"
exp_df = pd.read_csv(exp_fn, sep='\t', dtype=str, encoding='mbcs')
exp_df.to_csv(r"check.exp", sep='\t')
```

For this test case, it's desired that the check.exp file matches the test.exp file.
Using an IDE, you can inspect the dataframe post read and see what happened to 5.00".

I've been unable to discover the correct syntax for not mangling the embedded quote on either read or write.

In short, I sent this into a field:

```
"Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat"
```

But I got back:
`"Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00, chem film, lock washer and flat"""`

I'm looking to make the output match the input for a tab-delimited file, both input and output formatted the same.

Comment: Showing one line of your input file and (*at the same time*) a code that uses `skiprows=2`, is confusing. Does your file have a header or not ? Regardless, can you add a few more lines and specify, at the end, the exact matching expected output ?

Comment: Also provide the exact matching expected output.

Comment: Are the quotes around `<null>` supposed to be removed or preserved literally? I don't think you can have it both ways. If quotes around the field should be removed, then embedded quotes have to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  Yes, there are headers.  The quoted data snippet is exactly what the external program generates, with the quotes around the null.

Comment: The expected output is the same as the input without mutation.  For example if you absorb the line with a exp_df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep = '\t') then write it back out using pd.to_csv() it shouldn't strip/move the embedded quote in a true tab-delimited file

Comment: In this case, we are changing another field - it just happens that the ones with embedded quotes get mutated.

Comment: Hi , please edit your question and include a sample of what you expect that `... "Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00" ...` record to look like when parsed. I (we?) cannot tell from your longform description precisely what you expect/need the final data to look like.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question and providing some more context. You will still need to show us what literal values you expect, like `['PARTOCC:17306', '17306', 'M1', '48SL-5S-50-C-LF', 'Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat']`. Also, the SO code block seems to convert tabs to spaces, so you cannot rely on us seeing what you're starting with. I assume all the runs of spaces really represent tabs.

Comment: You're correct in that the file is tab-delimited of the format:"PARTOCC:17306"\t"17306"\t, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need that sample row to end up looking like:

```py
['PARTOCC:17306', '17306', 'M1', '48SL-5S-50-C-LF', 'Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat']
```

***and you know for certain*** that:

1. fields always have a beginning and ending (*enclosing*) double quote
2. fields do not contain a tab as value (that would need to be quoted)
3. fields do not contain any linebreak as a value (that would also need to be quoted)

you can try ignoring the quoting during parsing, and then removing the enclosing quotes manually with some simple string slicing.

The most naive approach looks like:

```py
import csv


rows: list[list[str]] = []
with open("input.txt", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    header = [x[1:-1] for x in next(reader)]  # consume, fix, and save header

    for row in reader:
        rows.append([x[1:-1] for x in row])


print(rows)
```

I ran that on the multiline sample in the question and I get:

```py
[
    ['PARTOCC:17306', '17306', 'M1', '48SL-5S-50-C-LF', 'Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat'],
    ['PARTOCC:17310', '17310', 'M2', '48SL-5S-50-C-LF', 'Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat'],
    ['PARTOCC:65494', '65494', 'J4E', '311P822-MC-095-BS-D', 'GSFC CPCI J3 RA MALE 95 Position 0.123" tails'],
]
```

Your requirement to then write the parsed and fixed results back out as you got them doesn't make sense to me.  If you just need to parse and ingest, stop there.  Why try to write a mis-encoded TSV file?  Maybe write the finally-correct encoding to help future programmers/operations?

```py
with open("output.txt", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

```
HEADER  ID  Part Reference  Value   Part_Description
PARTOCC:17306   17306   M1  48SL-5S-50-C-LF "Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00"", chem film, lock washer and flat"
PARTOCC:17310   17310   M2  48SL-5S-50-C-LF "Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00"", chem film, lock washer and flat"
PARTOCC:65494   65494   J4E 311P822-MC-095-BS-D "GSFC CPCI J3 RA MALE 95 Position 0.123"" tails"
```

### Update: input == output

Thinking about your comments and testing input vs output; the following attempts to codify the responsibility of parsing the bad TSV.  The codified values used to parse will then be used again to try and recreate the bad encoding.  I believe this program should prove that the codified ideas of decoding and encoding are correct, and that if the output equals the input, then the data wasn't changed inbetween:

```py
import sys

END = "\n"
"""expected line ending"""
DELIM = "\t"
"""expected delimiter"""
QUOT = '"'
"""expected quoting character"""

Row = list[str]


def decode(line: str) -> Row:
    """
    Decodes a badly encoded CSV/TSV line.

    Ensures line ends with END, split line on DELIM, and verify that
    each item (field) from the split begins and ends with QUOT then trim
    those enclosing QUOTs.

    Returns the fields as a new row.
    """
    if line[-len(END)] != END:
        raise ValueError(f"line doesn't end with {repr(END)}")

    line = line[: -len(END)]
    fields = line.split(DELIM)

    for i, field in enumerate(fields):
        if field[0] != QUOT or field[-1] != QUOT:
            raise ValueError(f"field {i} not enclosed in {repr(QUOT)}: {repr(field)}")

        fields[i] = field[1:-1]

    return fields


def encode(row: Row) -> str:
    """
    Encodes row back to its original, bad encoding.
    """
    line = DELIM.join([f"{QUOT}{field}{QUOT}" for field in row])
    return line + END


def exit_err(msg: str):
    print(msg, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)


rows: list[Row] = []
with open("input.txt") as f:
    try:
        header = decode(next(f))

    except ValueError as e:
        exit(f"couldn't decode header: {e}")

    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        try:
            rows.append(decode(line))

        except ValueError as e:
            exit(f"couldn't decode line {i}: {e}")


with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(encode(header))

    for row in rows:
        f.write(encode(row))
```

I run that like this:

```
python3 main.py; diff input.txt output.txt
```

and I get nothing, which means the output did equal the input.

### Update: roundtrip w/Andrej's approach

```py
import csv
import re
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open("input.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

text = re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+)"', r'\g<1>\\"', text)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), quotechar='"', sep="\t", escapechar="\\")

out_f = StringIO()

df.to_csv(
    out_f,
    sep="\t",
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
    doublequote=False,
    escapechar="\\",
    index=False,
)

text = out_f.getvalue().replace(r"\"", '"')

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach to the ingestion.  The reason to write it out in TSV format is because that's what's required; i.e. the program that we're updating its database can only import in TSV format.  We have better options for the master database.  For the "You know for certains", that's pretty much the definition of TSV for this program so those infractions would be caught by the program.  We also do "ISO testing" where we verify a tool hasn't changed by running test data, such as this, and ensuring the output data hasn't changed with a new tool rev.

Comment: @eric247, regarding writing and "ISO testing"... the data was mis-encoded to begin with, you handle that mis-encoding with an in-process solution like mine, or a pre-process solution like Andrej's, the data is now usable... **_and_** you have some requirement to prove that something bad or unintended didn't happen with those extra processing steps? I guess you could try to invent a way to re-mis-encode the data and write it out... but I don't see how that (only) proves that you read it correctly in the first place. Maybe you did read it incorrectly, but in writing you undo/hide that error?

Comment: @eric247, added an update that tries to deal with prove-ability.

Comment: Ultimately, the "re" approach had unintended side effects.  After testing, the hybrid of using your ingestion method and a modified version of the stringIO approach for output worked.    Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your file, it would be hard to parse without some pre-processing. You can use `re` module and add escape characters manually, e.g.:

```py
import re
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

text = """\
"HEADER"    "ID"    "Part Reference"    "Value" "Part_Description"
"PARTOCC:17306" "17306" "M1"    "48SL-5S-50-C-LF"   "Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat"
"PARTOCC:17310" "17310" "M2"    "48SL-5S-50-C-LF"   "Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat"
"PARTOCC:65494" "65494" "J4E"   "311P822-MC-095-BS-D"   "GSFC CPCI J3 RA MALE 95 Position 0.123" tails"
"""

text = re.sub(r'(\d+\.\d+)"', r'\g<1>\\"', text)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), quotechar='"', sep=r"\s+", escapechar="\\")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
          HEADER     ID Part Reference                Value                                                             Part_Description
0  PARTOCC:17306  17306             M1      48SL-5S-50-C-LF  Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat
1  PARTOCC:17310  17310             M2      48SL-5S-50-C-LF  Series 48SL–5 WEDGE–LOK, 2-56UNC-2B, 5.00", chem film, lock washer and flat
2  PARTOCC:65494  65494            J4E  311P822-MC-095-BS-D                                GSFC CPCI J3 RA MALE 95 Position 0.123" tails
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of these approaches got me there.
The issue I had was the libs that used df.to_csv() or df.read_csv() mutated the embedded doublequote in a valid tab separated values file.  To get around that, I tried both Zach's and Andrej's methods.

To write the dataframe out and avoid the lib code, like df.to_csv(), that mutated writing the embedded doublequote, it was basically not pretty.  Iterate through the dataframe row values, flatten to lists, iterate through the list and build up a string with the "\t" separator, write to file, e.g.

```
        row_list = exp_df.loc[i, :].values.flatten().tolist()
```

Thank you so much for the great suggestions!

Comment: Good job! You can use Pandas' to_csv method with the correct configuration to get back to regexp-replaced text Andrej suggested, then do a simple a text replace to undo that and get back to your original. I added an update to my answer that shows that.

Comment: One issue with the regular expression method.  In testing, one of the fields was "SDD104S4000G-1144.8" and the .8" ended up confusing the ingestion.

Comment: That makes sense: the regex being a broad pattern, and not really trying to parse. How’d my any of my solutions pan out in testing?